# EntityFramework reclamando de duplicidade de Identificador mesmo com a propriedade estando nula

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Possuo as seguintes classes:

**Produto**:

```cs
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(70)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Tamanho { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Preco { get; set; }
}
```

**Entrada**, que representa uma entrada em estoque:

```cs
public class Entrada
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Produto")]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double ValorCompra { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double ValorVenda { get; set; }
}
```

Em meu controller a Action que recebe o post para inserir um registro de entrada está assim:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(
    [Bind(Include = "Id, ProdutoId, DataCadastro, Quantidade, ValorCompra, ValorVenda")]
    EntradaModelEdit model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _service.AddAsync(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Somente pelo `Bind` na `Action` já é possível ver que a propriedade do tipo `Produto` vai ficar ***nula*** e somente a propriedade `ProdutoId` terá valor.

O método `AddAsync` da minha classe service está assim:

```cs
public async Task AddAsync(EntradaModelEdit model)
{
    using (var transaction = _repository.Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            await _repository.AddAsync(EntradaResolver.CreateEntradaFromModel(model));

            var produtoService = new ProdutoService(new ProdutoRepository(_repository.Context));
            await produtoService.AtualizarPrecoProdutoAsync(model.ProdutoId, model.ValorVenda);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

`EntradaResolver.CreateEntradaFromModel` é meu mapeador das classes de modelo de visão para às entidades do banco e vice-versa:

```cs
public static Entrada CreateEntradaFromModel(EntradaModel obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    return new Entrada
    {
        Id = obj.Id,
        ProdutoId = obj.ProdutoId,
        Produto = ProdutoResolver.CreateProdutoFromModel(obj.Produto),
        DataCadastro = obj.DataCadastro,
        Quantidade = obj.Quantidade,
        ValorCompra = obj.ValorCompra,
        ValorVenda = obj.ValorVenda,
    };
}
```

A de **Produto**:

```cs
public static Produto CreateProdutoFromModel(ProdutoModel obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    return new Produto
    {
        Id = obj.Id,
        Descricao = obj.Descricao,
        Tamanho = obj.Tamanho,
        Preco = obj.Preco
    };
}
```

E por fim, em meu repositório tenho o seguinte em `AddAsync`:

```cs
public async Task AddAsync(TEntity model)
{
    _context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

[image: print]

Após executar tais linhas de `AddAsync` do **Repository** já recebo o seguinte erro:

> Attaching an entity of type 'ControleRoupas.Domain.Entity.Produto' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

**Mas eu estou inserindo uma Entrada, e a propriedade Produto está nula, porque o EntityFramework acusa esse erro?**

Comment: Julgo que seja por causa de `ProdutoId = 1` e `Produto = null`. Terá de ler o *Produto* cujo id é 1 atribuí-lo a `Entrada.Produto`. Além disso tem de garantir que `_context.Entry(Produto).State == EntityState.Unchanged`

Comment: @ramaral, Porque isso acontece, sendo que nem sempre ocorre, costumo fazer inserções dessa forma.

Comment: Assim sendo terá de identificar o que está diferente em cada uma das situações.

Comment: @ramaral, Rapaz, difícil as vezes entender o que esse negócio quer. Entendi isso não.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema está relacionado com a forma como o Entity Framework faz tracking de objetos, que utiliza o [Identiy Map Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern), ou seja, somente uma única instância com a mesma chave primária pode ser anexada ao contexto.

No seu caso, o problema é que você anexou (mesmo que sem perceber) 2 entidades de produto com o mesmo Id. Primeiro você usou sua factory/mapeador pra criar um produto através do CreateEntradaFromModel(). A segunda instância provavelmente foi criada no seu serviço de AtualizarPrecoProdutoAsync (você não postou o código). Você deve passar a mesma instância que foi criada anteriormente pela sua factory.

Ao invés de passar o método como parâmetro ao repositório, guarde o retorno da sua factory em uma variável:

```
var entrada = EntradaResolver.CreateEntradaFromModel(model);
await _repository.AddAsync(entrada);

var produtoService = new ProdutoService(new ProdutoRepository(_repository.Context));
await produtoService.AtualizarPrecoProdutoAsync(entrada.Produto, model.ValorVenda);
```

Comment: A explicação está ok, mas o código não resolve o problema. Ainda há o agravante de o autor da pergunta ter usado um padrão de design que faz o EF trabalhar incorretamente para este caso. No caso da adição, o melhor é carregar o registro inteiro do produto e atribuir por objeto.

Answer (score 0):

O Entity Framework não trabalha bem quando você define uma chave estrangeira diretamente, como no caso de `Produto`. O correto seria algo como:

```
var produto = contexto.Produtos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
entrada.Produto = produto;
```

Ao fazer:

```
    ProdutoId = obj.ProdutoId,
    Produto = ProdutoResolver.CreateProdutoFromModel(obj.Produto),
```

O Entity Framework julga que você está criando um objeto novo, por mais que ele exista. Isto é ainda mais agravado no Entity Framework 6, em que entidades dependentes também são persistidas em cascata no `SaveChanges()`.