# Como funciona o Tracking / Chache de objetos do EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Sempre que utilizei o ***EntityFramework*** em um projeto, para adicionar um registro no banco de dados por meio dele, de uma classe que contenha membros de tipo de classes (geralmente por conta de *ForeignKeys*), eu fazia o seguinte:

1. Após a instância da entidade, preenchia as propriedades de tipos primitivos;
2. Setava as propriedades de tipos de classes como `null`.

E assim para mim sempre funcionou, até que em um caso específico como o que apresentei nessa questão: **[EntityFramework reclamando de duplicidade de Identificador mesmo com a propriedade estando nula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63007/entityframework-reclamando-de-duplicidade-de-identificador-mesmo-com-a-proprieda)**.

Há algumas questões aqui que tratam dessa questão, sempre casos isolados e uma forma de contornar.

1. Como, afinal de contas, funciona o *Tracking* de objetos do *EntityFramework?*
2. Ao trabalhar com ASP.NET MVC (projetos web) que funciona de forma a não manter informações em memória. Ou seja, o contexto do *EntityFramework* e todas as outras coisas são instanciadas quando uma requisição é feita e destruídas quando ela termina de retornar seu resultado. Logo, sempre que efetuo um *POST* para uma `Action`, que fará o `bind` de uma classe conforme parâmetro da `Action`, sei que tenho uma instância não monitorada pelo *EntityFramework*, certo? Por que então um simples:

```cs
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(model);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Funciona?

3. Como no caso da pergunta que referenciei, porque houve problemas de monitoramento?
4. Qual seria a forma mais "completa" para lidar com os `Inserts` e `Updates` e não ter problemas com o *Tracking* de objetos?
5. Habilitar ou Desabilitar o `LazyLoading` e criação de *proxies* e o monitoramento de alterações (`AutoDetectChangesEnabled`) afeta como o *Tracking*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Como, afinal de contas, o funciona o *Tracking* de objetos do *EntityFramework*?

Primeiro é importante explicar que um contexto existe durante o ciclo de vida de um *Controller*, no caso específico de você estar trabalhando usando o MVC. Os valores carregados pelo *Controller* só são expirados quando o *Controller* em questão sofre um [`Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), fazendo o contexto também sofrer um `Dispose`.

Ao carregar um objeto (em inglês chamam de *entry*, e eu vou chamar de registro), o registro é carregado com os valores originais do banco de dados, e eles ficam lá mesmo que você altere o registro. Isto faz com que, ao modificar um registro, o Entity Framework saiba que este registro já foi carregado previamente e saiba o que deve alterar.

O registro é localizado normalmente pela chave dele. Para entender isto melhor, é preciso entender a implementação do `DbSet<T>`. Ele é uma coleção observável ([`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Ao chamar [`SaveChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), o que está sendo feito é:

1. Conferir se alguma coleção está marcada como alterada;
2. Para cada registro que foi marcado como alterado, o Entity Framework executa alguma operação lógica para inserir, atualizar ou excluir um registro no banco de dados. A instrução executada está ligada a `EntityState`, um `Enum` usado para identificar o estado do registro dentro do Entity Framework.

## Logo, sempre que efetuo um POST para uma Action, que fará o bind de uma classe conforme parâmetro da Action, sei que tenho uma instância não monitorada pelo EntityFramework, certo?

Errado. Se o registro já foi carregado previamente (num `Edit`, por exemplo), ele já está sendo "observado". Ao aplicar um `POST` para salvar a edição, o objeto vindo da *View* é sincronizado da seguinte forma:

```
context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Repare que o contexto aqui é um contexto novo, sem a informação da requisição anterior. Quando digo "o registro já foi carregado previamente", digo que ele foi carregado em tela, e não em *Controller*. Ao realizar o `POST`, você está enviando informações e o contexto trabalha de forma otimista, ou seja, o registro é novamente carregado em `Entry()` caso já não tenha sido carregado.

Nesta linha são feitas duas coisas:

1. Localizar um registro com base em outro;
2. Atualizar os valores do registro observado com base nos registros em tela.

O caso do `Add` é mais simples. Você está dizendo ao contexto que o objeto não existe, então o contexto considera o objeto como novo.

## Como no caso da pergunta que referenciei, porque houve problemas de monitoramento?

Vou responder na pergunta.

## Qual seria a forma mais "completa" para lidar com os `Inserts` e `Updates` e não ter problemas com o *Tracking* de objetos?

- **Não** implementando repositórios (o Entity Framework já implementa repositórios);
- **Não** implementando camada de Serviço (*Controller* já é uma camada de serviços, diferente, mas é);
- **Não** instanciando dois contextos desnecessariamente;
- **Não** selecionando objetos em um contexto e tentando salvar no outro;
- Usando o código mais simples possível, conforme (quase) todos os exemplos ilustrados aqui e em outros sites especializados.

## Habilitar ou Desabilitar o `LazyLoading` e criação de *proxies* e o monitoramento de alterações (`AutoDetectChangesEnabled`) afeta como o *Tracking*?

Carga preguiçosa e monitoramento são coisas independentes. Uma não afeta a outra e vice-versa.

[`AutoDetectChangesEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.autodetectchangesenabled%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) faz o *tracking* não funcionar. Toda e qualquer alteração tem que ser invocada por métodos manuais.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que a resposta que você deu assume que está sendo usado um controller do template do Visual Studio que adiciona um DbContext no início da requisição e chama um dispose ao final. O que não é sempre o caso. Se eu estiver utilizando uma aplicação WPF ou Windows Forms, por exemplo, não há Controllers, ou seja, o ciclo de vida de um Contexto não está relacionado a um Controller. Mas gostei da sua didática para explicar, tenho que melhorar isso nas minhas respostas.

Comment: Que explicação excelente, obrigado! Mas não entendi o ciclo de vida do conroller. Eu executo um `Edit` e obtenho um registro (pensava que ao obter minha página carregada no browser o controller, e claro o contexto, já haveria sido destruído no servidor), e ao efetuar o **POST** que tudo já teria se perdido e com uma nova instância do controller e do contexto não haveria registros já em observação pelo entityFramework. Então o Controller só é destruído quando eu, em minha sessão, mudo de um controller para outro pela navegação?

Comment: Na outra questão o que eu faço é carregar os produtos para para criar um `DropDownList` com os produtos, porém utilizo o `AsNoTracking()`. Já o `ProdutoId` vêm da View, o value selecionado no `DropDownList`.

Comment: Pelo o que entendi aqui **[what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-asp-net-mvc-controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355139/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-asp-net-mvc-controller)**, o controller (e consequentemente o DbContext criado para ele, são criados a cada requisição e destruídos quando a requisição acontece. Então um ***GET*** ao ***Action Edit*** e depois um ***POST*** ao ***Action*** `[HttpPost] Edit(Model model)` é referente à criar e destruir  o controller (e o DbContext) duas vezes. Enfim, cada vez estou sem entender mais... rs =(

Comment: No comentário acima eu ressaltei que o ciclo de vida do DbContext não tem nada em haver com o ciclo de vida de um Controller. O que acontece é que como padrão geralmente um DbContext é instanciado com o Controller.

Comment: @Severo É isso mesmo. A cada requisição, o *Controller* destrói o `DbContext` ao final da requisição. Uma parte da resposta nao deixou isso claro, então vou editar.

Comment: @JonePolvora É que no caso dele, ele deixa claro que está usando ASP.NET MVC, não WPF, mas o princípio é o mesmo. Sobre a sua resposta, ela é complementar à minha e poderia muito bem ser a resposta aceita. Apenas gostaria que você aprendesse a sintaxe Markdown. Ela é bastante simples e pode ajudar um montão na hora de formatar uma resposta. Os links para ajuda com o Markdown ficam junto do painel resposta.

Comment: @Cigano eu conheço markdown, foi preguiça mesmo rsrs. Vou começar a melhorar a formatação e a didática nas respostas. Valew.

Comment: `um contexto existe durante o ciclo de vida de um Controller`. Isto é verdade apenas se você fizer o que está certo. Ou seja se o contexto não for um campo de classe mas sim de instância.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Normalmente é assim, certo? Outra coisa. Ainda que seja de classe, o `Dispose` descarta o contexto ao final da execução da requisição, com o descarte do *Controller*.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Answer (score 3):

São muitas perguntas pra responder, e um pouco complicadas, mas vou tentar

1 - O ChangeTracking do EntityFramework passa a monitorar uma instância de uma entidade após ela ser "attachada" (anexada) a uma instância de um DbContext.

2 - Quando você chama um método de um DbSet, por exemplo, Add(T model), o EntityFramework vai attachar o objeto ao DbContext e marcar o estado dele como Added.

Lembrando que você não pode anexar um mesmo objeto a duas instâncias distintas de DbContext

Você pode verificar qual o estado atual de um objeto através do método do Entry(object instance).

3 - O EntityFramework utiliza o [Identity Map Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern). Com isso, uma instância de DbContext só pode possuir uma única instância de um objeto com a mesma chave (Primary Key) anexada ao ChangeTracker. Por exemplo, se você carregou o registro com o Id = 1 de uma entidade Pessoa, você não pode anexar outro objeto com o mesmo Id = 1, senão você terá problemas.

4 - A melhor forma de tratar inserts e updates é isolar as operações com entidades de forma similar a uma transação. Uma instância de um DbContext deve ter uma vida curta, ou seja, você instancia o DbContext, faz o que precisa e logo em seguida descarta a instância. Preciso melhorar a resposta para esta questão 4, mas vou adiantando que  existe um NuGet package muito bom pra tratar updates mais complexos, chamado [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff).

5 - Eu não utilizo LazyLoading, nem recomendo, prefiro ter controle total sobre o que quero carregar do meu banco de dados e quando necessário carrego de forma prematura os dados que vou precisar, utilizando Include(). Então, por padrão eu desabilito. O Lazy Loading requer a criação de classes proxy, e requer que as propriedades da Entidade sejam virtuais. Quanto ao AutoDetectChanges, caso seja desabilitado, você terá que chamar o método DetectChanges() manualmente pra que o EntityFramework descubra quais as propriedades sofreram modificações na hora de gerar SQL que atualizam entidades.

Comment: +1 pelo GraphDiff. Sensacional o pacote.

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo mais interagir na outra questão. Também não consigo votar aqui. Apenas marcar a reposta como aceita. Bom, na outra pergunta, sobre o método `AtualizarPrecoProdutoAsync`, verdadeiramente obtenho o uma instância do produto ali para então alterar a propriedade `Preco` e então gravar a alteração. **Porém**, o erro acontece no método `AddAsync`, nesse momento ainda não foi executado o `AtualizarPrecoProdutoAsync`.

Comment: Na verdade, não é uma boa prática ficar passando uma instância de um contexto como parâmetro em várias camadas de sua aplicação (controller, serviço, repositório, etc.). Crie o seu DbContext só na implementação do seu Repositório. UnitOfWork + Repositório + EntityFramework não recomendo porque nunca se sabe o que foi feito em um DbContext nas outras camadas, você se perde muito fácil. http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: Sobre o `AtualizarPrecoProdutoAsync`, reitero, é o que você disse sim, exatamente isso! Me atrapalhei no debug com os `async's` da vida. Muito obrigado por sua explicação.